Python gRPC client not reusing HTTP2 connection
I have a Python gRPC server inside a Kubernetes cluster. The gRPC server implements a Ping method.
The server is load-balanced through Ingress Nginx, using the proper configuration (based on the official docs recommendations).
The server replies correctly to the request.
However, the Nginx logs show that a new HTTP/2 connection is initiated for each RPC call, despite re-using the same channel and the same stub.
NGINX logs
screen shot
│ ingress-nginx-controller-[...] 9.x.x.120 - - [07/Sep/2024:15:52:46 +0000] "POST /My.gRPC.Api/Ping HTTP/2.0" 200 [...]
│ ingress-nginx-controller-[...] 9.x.x.120 - - [07/Sep/2024:15:52:46 +0000] "POST /My.gRPC.Api/Ping HTTP/2.0" 200 [...]
│ ingress-nginx-controller-[...] 9.x.x.120 - - [07/Sep/2024:15:52:46 +0000] "POST /My.gRPC.Api/Ping HTTP/2.0" 200 [...]
│ ingress-nginx-controller-[...] 9.x.x.120 - - [07/Sep/2024:15:52:46 +0000] "POST /My.gRPC.Api/Ping HTTP/2.0" 200 [...]
│ ingress-nginx-controller-[...] 9.x.x.120 - - [07/Sep/2024:15:52:46 +0000] "POST /My.gRPC.Api/Ping HTTP/2.0" 200 [...]
│ ingress-nginx-controller-[...] 9.x.x.120 - - [07/Sep/2024:15:52:46 +0000] "POST /My.gRPC.Api/Ping HTTP/2.0" 200 [...]
│ ingress-nginx-controller-[...] 9.x.x.120 - - [07/Sep/2024:15:52:46 +0000] "POST /My.gRPC.Api/Ping HTTP/2.0" 200 [...]
│ ingress-nginx-controller-[...] 9.x.x.120 - - [07/Sep/2024:15:52:46 +0000] "POST /My.gRPC.Api/Ping HTTP/2.0" 200 [...]
│ ingress-nginx-controller-[...] 9.x.x.120 - - [07/Sep/2024:15:52:46 +0000] "POST /My.gRPC.Api/Ping HTTP/2.0" 200 [...]
│ ingress-nginx-controller-[...] 9.x.x.120 - - [07/Sep/2024:15:52:47 +0000] "POST /My.gRPC.Api/Ping HTTP/2.0" 200 [...]
│ ingress-nginx-controller-[...] 9.x.x.120 - - [07/Sep/2024:15:52:47 +0000] "POST /My.gRPC.Api/Ping HTTP/2.0" 200 [...]
│ ingress-nginx-controller-[...] 9.x.x.120 - - [07/Sep/2024:15:52:47 +0000] "POST /My.gRPC.Api/Ping HTTP/2.0" 200 [...]
│ ingress-nginx-controller-[...] 9.x.x.120 - - [07/Sep/2024:15:52:47 +0000] "POST /My.gRPC.Api/Ping HTTP/2.0" 200 [...]
│ ingress-nginx-controller-[...] 9.x.x.120 - - [07/Sep/2024:15:52:47 +0000] "POST /My.gRPC.Api/Ping HTTP/2.0" 200 [...]

Client code
The gRPC code that produced the above logs is the following:
import grpc

from my_lib.protos import api_pb2, api_pb2_grpc

host = "grpc.example.com"
credentials = grpc.ssl_channel_credentials()
channel = grpc.secure_channel(host, credentials)

stub = api_pb2_grpc.MyApiStub(channel=channel)
request = api_pb2.PingRequest(echo="ping")

for _ in range(15):
    stub.Ping(request=request)

Server code
The server is also implemented in Python.
import grpc

from my_lib.protos import api_pb2_grpc

class Server(api_pb2_grpc.MyApiServicer):
    async def Ping(self, request, context):
        return api_pb2.PingReply(echo=request.echo)


async def start_server():
    # I tried adding the following option, but no luck.
    options = [("grpc.max_concurrent_streams", 100)]
    server = grpc.aio.server(options=options)
    
    api_pb2_grpc.add_MyApi_to_server(Server(), server)
    # TLS termination is done by NGINX, traffic between NGINX
    # and this container is unencrypted
    server.add_insecure_port("[::]:5050")
    await server.start()

asyncio.run(start_server())

Question
I read everywhere that the HTTP/2 connection is expected to be re-used, and that multiple RPC calls should use the same TCP connection.
Why does a new HTTP connection is opened for each new call in my case ?
What am I missing?

Resources I've read (among dozens of others):

https://groups.google.com/g/grpc-io/c/icA68zR5L0U
https://github.com/grpc/grpc/issues/20985#issuecomment-552604012
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63435860


Could you please provide your current NGINX configuration?

The config is built from YAML declaration by Ingress Nginx. Here is the YAML: https://pastebin.com/fScuDU5K

I believe you need to add connection-ID to your logs. BR

@RoarS.do you mean "request-id" ? If so, here is new screenshot: you'll see that it's a different ID for each call https://i.imgur.com/1gsQT0l.png

@edthrn: No, I mean $connection as described here: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_connection. I suspect connection-id are the same for all requests. BR

A relevant article: https://blog.codavel.com/http2-multiplexing

Unfortunately, I don't see how to show "connection" in the logs using Ingress Nginx... https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/log-format/
Thanks for the article
